# "Ligue de Garage", au Québec. Comment traduire cette expression?

Tags: québec, sport, jargon

Nous avons une expression au Québec où l'on mentionne "Ligue de Garage":

> Est-ce que tu joues dans une **ligue de garage** ou bien tu joues à un plus haut niveau?

Pour décrire ce que c'est, ce sont quelques équipes "non-officielles" qui s'affrontent dans des parties de hockey aux courant des semaines mais ces équipes ne sont légiférées par aucune instance. Ce sont ces mêmes équipes qui s'organisent pour louer un terrain et y jouer tour à tour contre chacune des équipes. Mais rien n'est vraiment "officiel", comme par exemple la LNH (Ligue Nationalle de Hockey ou NHL).

Au Québec, nous appelons ça une "Ligue de Garage". Existe-t-il un terme, ailleurs dans la francophonie, pour désigner ce genre de ligue? Peu importe que ce soit une ligue de football (américain), soccer (football), hockey, rugby, etc.

Comment: Nothing to contribute to the good French part of your question, but in English, “sandlot” [games/leagues] is used, mostly baseball; “backyard” [games/leagues], mostly football; and “pick-up” [games/leagues] for any sport. “Garage (& ”Bush” & “Mickey Mouse”) are used with “League," but they’re most often used to insult the quality/management of an organized league/organization, such as [“Garage” is used here](http://www.russianmachineneverbreaks.com/2013/01/06/this-is-a-garage-league-and-other-lockout-lessons/). “Garage” is often used with “Band” in the way you mean when referring to musicians.

Comment: So, in other words, if you guys planned few games over the year against different teams for hockey, you'll say "Pick-up League"?

Comment: My suggestions (sandlot/backyard/pick-up) are most associated w/individual games &/or the general notion of the level of play, but they are also used to describe & even name leagues of this sort. [“Walk-on League”](http://www.operationsports.com/forums/college-hoops-2k-online/228454-college-hoops-walk-league.html) might also fit. “REC League” (short for RECreation) & [“House League”](http://www.hockeymom.com/#!travel-ice-hockey-vs-house-league/cowd) (as opposed to “Travel League”) are close, but they’re usually formed by local REC departments and/or rinks, so yes, I’d go with “Pick-up League.”

Comment: Je vois pas bien le terme "de Garage", en France en foot, il y a (entre autre) ligue 2/2eme division (professionnel), ... championnat corpo (équipe amateur). De garage impliquerait une notion de joueur "virés" du plus haut niveau mais qui essayent de jouer encore (aux US ou en Chine par exemple). Quel est le status des joueurs "de Garage" ? ex-pro, futur-pro, recalé ?

Comment: En fait, ce sont souvent des gens d'âges variées, sans nécessairement que ces derniers n'aient le même niveau. Dans mon cas, je n'ai jamais jouer dans aucune législation qu'il soit tant au niveau junior ou professionnel. J'ai appris à jouer avec des amis, dans la rue, au parc, etc. Mais je fais néanmoins parti d'une ligue de garage. Dans notre équipe il y a des joueurs de 16 ans comme il y en a de 55 ans. En bref, nous jouons parce que nous aimons ça, mais il n'y a pas de réel dénouement (pas de trophée ou quoi que ce soit)

Answer (score 4):

A première vue, je dirais un tournoi amateur (amateur dans le sens opposé de "professionnel")

Comment: Le mot "amateur" est bon en effet. Il y a aussi des ligues amateurs, pas seulement des tournois (ligues ou tournois, ça se réfère au mode de compétition). Par anglicisme j'ai aussi déjà entendu "ligue corporate" pour les matches entre équipes de sociétés différentes

Comment: Tournois fait à mon avis, trop solennelle pour ce qu'est une ligue de garage au Québec. Le terme tournois laisse croire que cela s'échelonne sur une courte durée (une fin de semaine ou deux maximum). Tandis qu'une ligue de garage dure habituellement de l'automne au début de l'été. En fait, quelques équipes de ligue de garage participe souvent à des tournois régionale amateurs. Je dis seulement pour différencier les termes selon notre utilisation ici, entre nous, au Québec. C'est peut-être le cas ailleurs en fait.

Comment: Le mot tournoi n'implique pas pour moi de notion de durée. Un tournoi peut fort bien s'étaler sur plusieurs mois. Exemple : le tournoi des six nations.

Answer (score 1):

On rencontre souvent « football sauvage » ou « de pied d'immeuble » pour définir cette pratique hors du cadre des fédérations sportives, mais on va probablement plus loin que ces « ligues de garage » car il n'y a pas ici de location de terrain.

Référence: https://sociologies.revues.org/2763?lang=fr

Comment: Je pense que les *ligues de garage* sont construites selon le modèle des ligues professionnelles, avec des classements, des équipes qui ont un nom et un logo, des rencontres organisées, etc. Je ne sais pas si le terme de *football sauvage* ou *de pied d'immeuble* prend en compte cette dimension, qui n'existe peut-être même pas en France.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Oui, je suis d'accord. Ce type de tournoi hors fédération mais néanmoins formel n'existe probablement pas en France, sauf dans le cadre par exemple d'une colonie ou d'un club de vacances, d'une base de loisirs, d'une fête locale, etc.

Comment: _De pied d'immeuble_ ça correspondrait sans doute à _de ruelle/dans'rue(lle)_ au Québec. C'est que le hockey sur glace demande légèrement plus d'organisation, et donc s'improvise moins bien. En plus je crois qu'en France on n'a pas _vente de garage_, même si on a _voie de garage_. Moi je me demande si le _garage_ ds. la vente et celui de la ligue est le même, ou si ce dernier c'est le garage en anglais mais sans la connotation que mentionne Papa Poule. C'est bien intéressant !

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ Oui pas de hockey sur glace sauvage en France, et pas de «vente de garage » non plus. C'est le calque de *garage sale*. Le plus proche serait une brocante, mais cette dernière est organisée et collective, pas individuelle.

Comment: @jlliagre Il y a bien des "vide grenier" ou "vide maison" qui sont individuels, quand des gens déménagent par exemple, mais en effet bien plus rare

Comment: Oui, il s'agit de « ventes au déballage » privées, assez encadrées juridiquement ( https://vide-greniers.org/reglementation ).

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ Pour moi, le garage dans "Garage Band" parle literalement (et pas figurativement, comme dans "ligue de garage") du lieu exact ou ces groupes repetent (if they're like the one I was in in the 60s, rehearse is all they do 'cause we never got a paying gig!), faute des oreilles fragiles des parents & grace au fait que nos garages ici servent rarement pour garer nos chars. Pour "Garage Sale," c'est un peu plus figuratif je crois, mais litteral quand meme dans le sens que les trucs vendus sont souvent stockés dans les garages (les guitares poussiereuse, par ex, mais pas les bagnoles).

Comment: @PapaPoule Je pense que le nom *Garage Sale* vient plus du lieu où a lieu la vente (garage ou pente de garage) plutôt que du lieu où sont préalablement stockés les biens vendus, c.f. *Yard Sale*.

Comment: It’s certainly true that *Garage Sales* can and do occur in or around garages, in which case the term’s use becomes strictly literal (as in *Garage Band*). Even if the term can be viewed as an ellipse of “[Please-help-me-clear-out-the-junk-in-my-] Garage Sale” (which is what I was, perhaps wrongly, suggesting), there’s still a literal/logical connection with “garage” that I find missing in “ligue/hockey de garage,” where actually playing hockey in an individual’s garage would be tough to do.

Comment: @PapaPoule I want to stress how insightful is the info you provided into usage and especially about those per-sport league names ! Oui je comprends l'idée de garage et il y a cette connotation avec le groupe de musique ; le GDT note vente de garage comme calque mais n'a pas un truc comme ligue de garage, et il peut arriver que l'emprunt soit adapté ou utilisé différemment. La connotation existe peut-être au Québec ds. certains contextes, comme ds. une comparaison ou un cas où l'on contredit quelqu'un avec ça etc., mais pas à mon avis dans le sens de la question, où c'est p-ê plus neutre. Merci