# « Mise en vente à prix réduits, par un particulier, sur sa propriété, d'objets dont il veut se défaire » ?

Tags: usage, terminologie, france, commerce, belgique

Il s'agit d'un défi semblable à celui que soulève une [autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/21644) et qui fait en sorte qu'on ne sache pas exactement comment on réfère ailleurs qu'au Québec à la :

> Mise en vente à prix réduits, par un particulier, sur sa propriété,
>   d'objets dont il veut se défaire.
>
> [ *Grand dictionnaire terminologique* de l'OQLF, GDT, [*vente-débarras*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1299797) ]

Le GDT a identifié le calque de l'anglais *garage sale*, soit la *vente de garage*, qu'il trouve inutile, et suggère la *vente-débarras* depuis quasiment 40 ans. À mon avis, c'est que le mot *débarras* est un peu chargé ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9barras), [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/d%C3%A9barras/21762)) d'une connotation négative ou se centre sur la perspective de celui qui vide son débarras (son garage, son grenier, sa grange que sais-je), ou qui se débarrasse de ces objets, et *bon débarras* ! (on emploie aussi l'expression quand on est content de voir des gens *débarrasser le [plancher](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/plancher/61361/locution?q=d%C3%A9barrasser#164586)*) Le GDT note *vide-grenier* et *vide de fond de grenier* pour la France et la Belgique respectivement, dans le sens *privé* du terme. Mais on ne sait pas si c'est [usuel](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/21646), s'il y a d'autres expressions, si le lieu d'où originent les biens importe littéralement, et on ne retrouve pas ces termes dans les dictionnaires (*Larousse*, *TLFi*, *Franceterme*).

---

- Y a-t-il une parfaite adéquation entre les termes *vide-grenier/vide
  de fond de grenier* et la définition présentée plus haut ; faut-il nuancer ? S'agit-il bien des termes employés en France et en Belgique respectivement ?
- Ces termes sont-ils les plus usuels : quand on se promène en ville à
  pieds par exemple et qu'à des dizaines de mètres de soi on voit que
  quelqu'un a installé soit une table soit un morceau de tissu sur la
  pelouse ou à un autre endroit de sa propriété ou de l'immeuble qu'il loue, et y a disposé divers objets afin de les vendre (aux passants), comment s'exprime-t-on là-dessus :

  > Regarde, il y a/quelqu'un (fait) (un/une) [**X**], veux-tu aller
  >   jeter un coup d’œil ?

Comment: [Pour compléter ta question](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vide-greniers).

Comment: @Laure Merci, l'article est intéressant ! Par ailleurs puisqu'il assimile la _vente de garage_ du Québec à un _rassemblement populaire_, il s'avère inexact ou imprécis à cet égard. Cet aspect semble difficile à cerner pour je ne sais quelle raison.

Comment: [Here’s](http://tendancesmode-style.blogspot.com/2013/08/vente-de-garage-st-laurent.html) a mix of uses of “vente de garage/parking” from Montreal, w/some seeming to be literal to the max (the actual sale of garages/parking spaces)! This hyper-literal sense also seems to exist in France, [at least in classified ads](http://www.seloger.com/immobilier/achat/immo-paris-75/bien-parking/). cf a less literal use of [vente de box](http://www.location-gardemeuble.fr/blog/exclusivite-ventes-aux-encheres-de-garde-meubles/) to mean “VENTE [aux enchères des contenus] DE BOX [de stockage/garde-meubles]."

Comment: @PapaPoule That first link is quite something, that must be SEO oriented because it mixes it all together !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La dénomination officielle recouvrant cette activité est **vente au déballage** mais elle n'est quasiment pas utilisée en dehors des documents à remplir en Mairie et de la législation s'y attachant.

**Vide-grenier** est en revanche une expression très courante en France, comme aussi **brocante** et **braderie**. Il existe aussi des noms plus localisés comme **foire à tout** en Normandie.

Cependant, à la différence des *garage sales*, un **vide-grenier** ne se déroule qu'exceptionnellement devant ou dans la propriété du vendeur, mais plutôt dans un lieu unique où se regroupent tous les participants du vide-grenier. Ce peut être une place ou une rue d'une commune fermée à la circulation pour l'occasion.

Il peut arriver qu'un particulier vende ses biens sur sa pente de garage et la loi l'y autorise après déclaration à la mairie, mais c'est très rare.

https://vide-greniers.org/reglementation

https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F22397

Comment: Il me semble que le terme de « vide-greniers » est différemment utilisé sur le territoire français. En Normandie on a des  « foires à tout » qui ne sont rien d'autres que des vide-greniers (je crois que c'est invariable. **s** sing. et plur.)  Dans le nord de la France ils ont des « braderies », n'est-ce pas la même chose ?

Comment: @Laure Oui, j'ai déjà mentionné brocante et braderie qui sont des termes plus ou moins équivalents. Je ne connaissait pas « foire à tout » qui semble effectivement très lié à la Normandie.

Comment: Oui, très lié à la Normandie, je n'ai jamais vu de foire à tout dans le midi ou de braderie en Normandie ou dans le midi !

Comment: Si le vide-grenier peut se dérouler exceptionnellement sur la propriété du vendeur, il peut être utile d'ajouter que cette exception ne s'applique pas aux brocantes ou aux braderies?

Comment: @Qoba Brocante et vide-grenier sont plus ou moins synonymes en région parisienne, et braderie sera plus souvent rencontré dans le nord de la France. Rien n'interdit à quelqu'un qui l'a déclaré et satisfait aux conditions requises de mettre en vente des objets devant sa maison durant une brocante ou une braderie ayant lieu dans sa commune.

Comment: Oui mais peut-il décider seul de mettre en vente son bric-à-brac sur la pelouse devant chez lui, un beau dimanche, sans que sa commune n'organise quoi que ce soit, et encore appeler ça une brocante? Il me semblait que vide-grenier pouvait marcher dans ce cas.

Comment: @qoba Il doit prévenir sa commune quinze jours à l'avance. Vide-grenier semble plus naturel ici c'est vrai mais aucun dictionnaire ne lui interdit d'appeler ça une brocante ou une braderie.

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ J'en doute vu qu'on reste dans le cadre de transactions commerciales régies par le code du commerce. Au-delà on sort de la loi.

Comment: Venant du Midi, pour moi une _braderie_ concerne principalement de la vente de vêtements où les vendeurs sont généralment des professionels et lorsque les vendeurs sont des particuliers on dira plutôt _vide-dressings_. Ensuite je pense au _marché aux puces_ qui selon moi est aussi un équivalent de _brocante_ ou _vide-greniers_.

Comment: @Remi A l'origine, une braderie est une foire annuelle dans les Flandres, on y brade (à l'origine « griller », comme les *bratwurst*) de tout, en particulier des moules et des frites. Un marché au puces est, contrairement aux brocantes et vide-greniers, situé sur un lieu qui ne change pas et avec une occurrence régulière, mensuelle, hebdomadaire, voire quotidienne.

Comment: @jlliagre Je suis aussi du midi et je confirme tout à fait ce que dit Rémi sur l'usage du mot braderie dans le midi, ou une braderie n'est pas un vide greniers.

Comment: @Rémi Le terme de marché aux puces ne couvrent pas la même chose sur toute la France, effectivement dans le midi il y a des puces ouvertes aux non professionnels (le marché aux puces de Toulouse, par exemple) mais dans beaucoup d'endroits on ne trouve dans les puces que des professionnels de la récup.

Comment: Ça dépend sûrement de qui est « on ».

Comment: Ça n'explique toujours pas qui se cache derrière « on » dans la question...